# Creating Dynamic Filters in Tableau

Tags: filtering, tableau-api

I'm working in Tableau to help my school district visualize discipline data.  I want to be able to disaggregate and filter by quite a few different measures (at least 13).

In the past, if I wanted to be able to disaggregate by a number of measures, I would make a parameter with a list of possible outputs, display each output as the name of a measure, then create a calculated field that returned the value from a given measure based on that parameter.  This works fine for disaggregating.

However, filtering based on these values presents a challenge.  The problem is that I'm not filtering based on any given measure, I'm filtering on a calculated field that returns the value in that measure.  If my parameter is set to "Day" for instance, and I filter to Tuesday, but then switch to "Race", everything vanishes, because now my calculated field is returning race.  What I want to create is a dropdown menu that lets you select from a number of different measures to filter by.

Below is a link to a packaged workbook that can help illustrate the problem that I'm dealing with.

I feel like something like this should be possible in Tableau, but there's some little trick that I'm missing.  When I contacted their support team, their solutions were both only viable due to the limited number of measures I was using in the dummy data.  The support team felt that this was possible as well, but they didn't know how.

https://public.tableau.com/profile/publish/DynamicFiltersUsingParameters/Sheet1#!/publish-confirm

Answer (score 0):

You could create an [Filter Action](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/actions.html) on the Tableau dashboard which carries over the 'Day' filter to give a smaller subset of data to work with for the next filter.